# How to Extract the texts behind the "Read More" in reviews?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

[This is the inspected source code image of the review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3sZZ.png)

If i use that class in the python for extraction. It just return "READ MORE" string, It cant get the text behind the "READ MORE"
My code is,

```
extra = []
e = j.find_all('span', {'class' : '_1EPkIx'})
extra.append([k.get_text() for k in e])
```

and it returns

```
[['READ MORE', 'READ MORE', 'READ MORE', 'READ MORE', 'READ MORE', 'READ MORE', 'READ MORE', 'READ MORE']]
```

Do you have any idea about this???

Comment: you have to automate the thing using selenium.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of javascript events are handled by selenium but not beautifulsoup.

```py
import selenium
selenium.webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('span._1EPkIx').click()
```

after that you can fetch *webdriver*.page_source and there suppose to be whole text